# i want to delete multible inputs by notepad++

Tags: notepad++

i have this regular expression

replace this

^(\d+.\d+.\d+.\d+ )(.+)\r\n(\1.+\r\n)*

to

\1\2\r\n

it's make this results

replacing this

```
109.172.14.61 : 1 : 1
109.172.14.61 : 1 : 8888
109.172.14.61 : 2 : 1234
109.172.14.61 : 2 : 8888
109.172.60.153 : 73 : 73
109.188.66.153 : 11 : 0000
109.188.66.153 : 11 : 123456
109.188.83.137 : 2010 : 22222
```

to this

```
109.172.14.61 : 1 : 1
109.172.60.153 : 73 : 73
109.188.83.137 : 2010 : 22222
```

but i need another result

i want this

```
109.172.14.61 : 1 : 1
109.172.14.61 : 1 : 8888
109.172.14.61 : 2 : 1234
109.172.14.61 : 2 : 8888
109.172.60.153 : 73 : 73
109.188.66.153 : 11 : 0000
109.188.66.153 : 11 : 123456
109.188.83.137 : 2010 : 22222
```

to this

```
109.172.14.61 : 1 : 1
109.172.14.61 : 2 : 1234
109.172.60.153 : 73 : 73
109.188.66.153 : 11 : 0000
109.188.83.137 : 2010 : 22222
```

any help please !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a try with:

Find what: `^(\d+(?:\.\d+){3}\s+:\s+\d+)(.+?)\R(?:\1.+?\R)*`
Replace with: `$1$2\r\n`

**Explanation:**

```
^           : start line
(           : begin capture group 1
  \d+       : 1 or more digits
  (?:       : begin NON capture group
    \.      : a dot
    \d+     : 1 or more digits
  ){3}      : non capture group repeated 3 times
  \s+       : 1 or more space
  :         : semi-colon
  \s+       : 1 or more space
  \d+       : 1 or more digits
)           : end of group 1
(           : begin group 2
  .+?       : 1 or more any character but newline non greedy
)           : end group 2
\R          : any kind of line break (\n or \r\n or \r)
(?:         : begin non capture group
  \1        : same content as group 1
  .+?       : 1 or more any character but newline non greedy
  \R        : any kind of line break (\n or \r\n or \r)
)*          : non capture group repeated 0 or more times.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, because the suffix number is the unique one that can be checked whether the string should be deleted or replaced：

(\d{1,3}.){4}\s:\s\d{1,2}\s:\s(8888|123456)